# How can I determine the resolution of incoming RTMP streams with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, rtmp, transcoding

I'm using ffmpeg to transcode RTMP from my own RTMP server into HLS ready H.264. At the moment, I'm executing a command of the following form

```
ffmpeg -i rtmp://<ip>:<port> <options for 480p> <options for 720p30> <options for 720p60> <options for 1080p>
```

This is causing me to attempt to transcode lower resolutions to higher resolutions.

The RTMP server I'm using is [nginx with RTMP module](https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module)

Is there a way I can determine the source resolution, so that I only transcode into resolutions smaller than the source one?

Comment: Not in a single step. You need to probe the stream, then set the ffmpeg options based on the result.

Comment: this might be helpful for you. https://superuser.com/questions/841235/how-do-i-use-ffmpeg-to-get-the-video-resolution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @szatmary's comment I have found the following solution:

I can use the command line tool ffprobe to get information about a stream. [Here is the documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html)

It says [here](https://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html#Description) that

> If a url is specified in input, ffprobe will try to open and probe the url content. If the url cannot be opened or recognized as a multimedia file, a positive exit code is returned.

ffprobe can be configured to use different writers and writing options so that it can return results in a range of formats.

Comment: this is very useful. Could you share an example or working example of this ? NginX config with FFmpeg commands.